# Highly divisible triangular number in java: Program inefficiency

Tags: java

I am writing code to compute first number which has over 500 divisors, however, due to some inefficiency the program is taking too long to process. Here is my code:

```
public class Lessons {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a,b;
        int triangle=0;



        for (a=1;a>0;a++)
        {
           triangle += a;
           int count=0;

           for (b=1;b<=triangle; b++)
           {    
                if (triangle%b==0)
               {    
                   count += 1;
                }
            }
        if (count > 500)
        {
            System.out.println("The number is " + triangle);
            break;
        }
     }
    }}
```

Any helps??

Answer (score 3):

When your limit is `b <= triangle` it's inefficient. You can test upto the square root of the number. Take for example the number 100 - you have to loop upto 10, not 100. If it divides by 5, then you have found two divisors - 5 and 20. The first is lower then 10, and the other bigger. The only thing you should check is the root itself - it gives you only one divisor.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    int number, limit, divisors;
    int i;
    Boolean found = false;

    number = 1;
    while (!found) {
        divisors = 0;
        limit = (int)Math.sqrt(number);
        i = 1;
        if (number % limit == 0) divisors++;
        while (i < limit) {
            if (number % i == 0) divisors +=2;
            i++;
        }
        if (divisors >= 500) {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("" + number);
        }
        number++;
    }
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

Run it and wait a minute or two, depends on your machine ):

Comment: I tried applying your suggestion but somehow it stills fails to speed things up. Can you please post the rectified code???